# Использование API с ограничением на количество запросов в приложении android

Tags: java, android, api

Пишу приложение для android с использованием API, которое имеет ограничение по количеству запросов в день (1000). Как правильно действовать в этих случаях? Создавать отдельное приложение на ПК, которое будет работать с базой данных? В общем, я совсем новичок, поэтому идей у меня нет

Answer (score 3):

Ну, возможно поможет создание нескольких акков у предоставителя API и при использовании в приложении генерировать число от 0 до кол-ва акков и обращаться к API через этот акк. Так вы не будете ограничены кол-вом запросов, если верно рассчитаете нужное кол-во акков и если в правилах пользования API это не запрещено (или если не заметят) и если это технически возможно.

Добавление от @Roman Novoselov:

как правило сервис возвращает причин отказа - анализируйте его, если причина - превышение количетсва запросов, то используйте след ключ. Ну и максимально минимизаруйте количество запросов. Например поддерживал приложение испольщзующее Google Maps Place API (автозаполнение названия города по введеной части названия) - после того как количество запросов тало превышать, ста запрашивать данные лишь после количества введеных букв кратных трем, при пробелах и дефисах. Но тут уже у каждого свой путь )